# Laravel - How to Sum relative table with limit result?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have these 2 models.

I want to get sum of 12 columns `comment_count` in `youtube_video_insights` table.

How can I do that with Query Builder or Eloquent.

I try to use something like in my Repository this but it didn't work.

It's just sum all the `comment_count` columns.

```
$this->youtube_channel_insight
            ->join('youtube_video_insights',function ($q){
                $q->on('youtube_channel_insights.id','=','youtube_video_insights.youtube_channel_insight_id')
                    ->orderBy('youtube_video_insights.id','desc')
                    ->limit(12);
            })
            ->where('youtube_channel_insights.id',$id)
            ->select(\DB::raw(
                "SUM(youtube_video_insights.comment_count) as total_comment"
            ))->get();
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YoutubeChannelInsight extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(YoutubeVideoInsight::class);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class YoutubeVideoInsight extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the structure of your tables are:

for **youtube_channel_insights**'s table you have :

```
id | name
----------------------------------------
1  | channel_01
2  | channel_02
```

and for **youtube_video_insights**'s table you have:

```
id | channel_id|    name    | comment_count
----------------------------------------
1  |     1     |  video_01  |      20
2  |     1     |  video_02  |      40
3  |     2     |  video_03  |      5
4  |     2     |  video_04  |      15
```

Now you should wright your query like this:

```
$sub1 = YoutubeVideoInsight ::select('comment_count', 'channel_id')
->whereRaw('channel_id = 2')->orderBy('id', 'Desc')->limit(2);

$sub2 = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub1->toSql()}) as sub"))
->select(DB::raw('
SUM(`comment_count`) AS total_comment,
channel_id
'));


return $query = YoutubeChannelInsight ::joinSub($sub2,'sub2',function($join){
$join->on('channels.id','=','sub2.channel_id');
})->get();
```

Comment: The thing is I want to get sum of limit 12 results ```limit(12)```. 
The structure of my tables is right but I don't understand what is TotalCatch or TotalCatches in your code